# Proper object usage in a simple game setting

Tags: c++, object

Assuming that I wanted to make a simple dos-based game and I wanted to create some mobs, I've come up with the following rough object that I would need, and it looks something like this:

```
class createMob{ 
    private:
        int healthMax;
        int healthCurrent;
        int manaMax;
        int manaCurrent;
        int experiencePoints;

public:
    void setHealth();
    int getHealth();
    void setCurrentHealth();
    int getCurrentHealth();

    void setMaxMana();
    int getMaxMana();
    void setCurrentMana();
    int getCurrentMana();

    int getExperience();
//etc etc functions truncated for space


};
```

My question is how do I use this?  Assume that I create a simple constructor to take in a hp / mp / experience for a mob called "green slime" (final fantasy theme going on here).  My basic goal is to create a monster with x / y /z attributes and set them based on what happens in combat... What would be the easiest way to do this and then clean up efficiently afterwards?

Comment: Are you sure that `createMob` is a good name? I'd recommend `baseMob`, or something similar because you'll probably be deriving from this class quite a bit. The name indicates to me that the class is some sort of factory class, which given the layout just isn't correct.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You basically ask how to write the program.

Comment: green slime is a Dragon Quest theme, not Final Fantasy.

Comment: This is too open-ended a question to be answered here, probably.  Many games have a collection of all the objects in a game, and a loop that goes through all the objects and updates their state for each unit of time.

Comment: @llya Kogan -- I'm more asking how should I use my base class to create a simple mob.  I understand how the functions will interact, I'm just not sure if I should be storing all these mobs in a separate file, or if I should be creating them at the time of encounter, or anything like that.  I'm having issues with both the logic and the implementation, but only when it comes to the object side of things.

Comment: @Raskolnikov -- You're right, I think that I actually will rename it and make other things inherit from it... it's weird, I know how to handle inheritance, but I can't make a simple mob to kill...

Comment: question is not broad, it's specific as hell.  People are so mean.

Comment: you don't need a createmob class.  you need a mob class.  put the initialization code in the mob consructor where it belongs, and create mobs with new()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two mobs in a fight, the fight is going to take longer than one turn, so one fight turn is going to need the following global function:

```
void fight(Mob &m1, Mob &m2, int fightstep);
```

Now this function can change properties of both mobs. Now if mobs are actually doing some actions to choose how the fight is going, you'll need something different:

```
void fight(Mob &m1, Mob &m2, 
           std::vector<Action> vec1, std::vector<Action> vec2, 
           int fightstep);
```

with the action being something like this:

```
enum Action { EDoNothing, EBash, ECastSpellXXXX ... };
```

Now the fight functions can use the interface of Mob class to do the changes.